# .removeClass Method Unresponsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to sort out why the .removeClass method is not working on our home page drop-down menus. Here's the relevant HTML markup:

```
<div id="categorynav">

    <div id="manufacturers" class="categorybox">

        <div id="manufacturershead" class="category_head"><h1>Manufacturers</h1></div>

        <div id="manufacturersbody" class="category_body">

            <a href="#" class="more">MORE</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a>some menu item</a></li>
                <li><a>some menu item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div

    </div>

    <div id="categories" class="categorybox">

        <div id="categorieshead" class="category_head"><h1>Categories</h1></div>

        <div id="categoriesbody" class="category_body">

            <a href="#" class="more">MORE</a> 

            <ul>
                <li><a>some menu item</a></li>
                <li><a>some menu item</a></li>
            </ul>

       </div>

    </div>

    <div id="applications" class="categorybox">

        <div id="applicationshead" class="category_head"><h1>Application Notes</h1></div>

        <div id="applicationsbody" class="category_body"> 

            <a href="#" class="more">MORE</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a>some menu item</a></li>
                <li><a>some menu item</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

And here is the CSS, as it relates to the .active class, with the original programmer's comments (if I need to elaborate on the code, I can):

```css
/*active state for category_head */

#categorynav .active {
background-position:0 0;
background-color: #003399;
color: #000;
}

.category_head h1 {
font-size:20px;
color:#ffffff;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
padding-top:10px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Lastly, the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

// add some clicks:
$('#manufacturershead, #manufacturers .more').click(load_manufacturers);
$('#categorieshead, #categories .more').click(load_categories);
$('#applicationshead, #applications .more').click(load_applications);

function load_manufacturers() {
    $('#category_temp').load('load_manufacturersbox.php').fadeIn('slow');
    $('.category_head').removeClass('active');
    $('#manufacturershead').addClass('active');
    return false;
}
function load_categories() {
    $('#category_temp').text('Loading...');
    $('#category_temp').load('load_categoriesbox.php',addAZbar).fadeIn('slow');
    $('.category_head').removeClass('active');
    $('#categorieshead').addClass('active');
    return false;
}
function load_applications() {
    $('#category_temp').fadeOut();
    /*
    $('#category_temp').load('load_applicationsbox.php').fadeIn('slow');
    */
    $('.category_head').removeClass('active');
    $('#applications').addClass('active');
    return false;
}   
function addAZbar() {
    $('#categories_list').listnav({
        noMatchText: '<span class="warning">Please click another letter.</span>',
        prefixes:['the','a'],
        onClick: function(letter){ letterchange(letter); }
    });
    function letterchange(letter) {
        if (letter == 'all') { $('#categories_list').addClass('all') ;}
        else {
            $('#categories_list').removeClass('all') ;
        }

    }

};


});
</script>
```

I simply want the user to be able to close the menu without navigating away from the home page.  To reiterate, the .removeClass('active') method is not working properly, or else there is something wrong with the CSS. Those are my two guesses, but I haven't been able to troubleshoot the issue on my own.  I would greatly appreciate some help--our senior developer is out for the day.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8zrbz2ab/

Comment: You have a malformed closing `</div>` tag on the 10th line down (count excludes blank line).  It looks like this: `</div`.

Comment: You're using `.category_head` in numerous cases. Are you sure you want to remove the class from all category heads? etc. categories, manufacturers and applications?

Comment: When I tried running this code, the add/remove of the active class worked fine.  When I click categories "more" it adds the class and removes from navigation. Are you wanting to `toggle()` the class when they click the same item? http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  I'll check into these fixes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i cant make comments, but the only error i found so far was this line

`$('#applications').addClass('active');`

should be

`$('#applicationshead').addClass('active');`

youshould add the class active to #applicationshead and not the entire div.
(i dont know if php could be getting in the way of removeclass, but here is a fiddle without the php part)
http://jsfiddle.net/caawtvfs/

Comment: That was actually the first thing I noticed and tried...still no response.